# jcarousel plugin is not working in sitecore preview mode

Tags: jquery, sitecore, page-editor

jcarousel plugin is working when we run the page on browser but if we run the same page in sitecore preview mode(In sitecore: Click on Presentation in the top menu. Click on Preview in the ribbon) then this plugin is not working. please let me know if you have solution that would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of **Sitecore** do you use? I think the problem might be with **jquery** conflicting with **prototype**.

You can try to use **jquery** in `noConflict` mode:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

In nutshell, add this line before the place you initialize your jcarousel, e.g.:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); // switch jquery to noconflict mode

$j('.jcarousel').jcarousel(); // this is your initalization of jcarousel
```

More explanation in [jquery conflicts with pageeditor article](http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2009/01/jquery-conflicts-with-pageeditor.html)

Comment: where should we declare this variable on 1 page or in plugin? And we are using sitecore 6.6

Comment: Personally, I prefer anonymous functions and isolating scope. Allows you to continue using $ in all your code. http://blog.navigationarts.com/avoiding-jquerys-noconflict-mode-with-prototype-and-sitecore/ But same difference.

Comment: @jammykam brilliant idea! Haven't seen that before