# boxslider plugin is not working in sitecore preview mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, sitecore, bxslider, sitecore7.2

Boxslider plugin is working when we run the page on browser but if we run the same page in Sitecore `Preview` mode (in Sitecore: click on `Presentation` in the top menu then click on `Preview` in the ribbon) then this plugin is not working.

I have also followed this link below, but it doesn't work for me.

[jcarousel plugin is not working in sitecore preview mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680289/jcarousel-plugin-is-not-working-in-sitecore-preview-mode)

Please let me know if you have solution that would be helpful.

Comment: Do you have any javascript errors?

Comment: yes 1.  Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: 2. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined

Comment: in jquery.noconflict.js

Comment: TypeError: a.ownerDocument is undefined in jquery.nonconflict.js

Comment: Which version of Sitecore do you use?

Comment: Sitecore 7.2 rev. 140228

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to put jquery.min.js and jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js references on bottom of page as well, I believe It will work for you.

Please let me know if it's not work for you.